# How to change font-size of a tag using inline css?

Tags: css

Can't change font-size of a tag for given below code

```
<td valign="top" width="620"><strong><a href="images/pub/pub1.pdf" target="_self">Factsheet of the OSCE Border Management Staff College</a></strong><br /><br /><strong><span style="font-size: 11px; color: #aaaaaa;">14 June 2013</span></strong>
```

Tried:

```
<td valign="top" width="620"><strong><a style="font-size:14px;" href="images/pub/pub1.pdf" target="_self">Factsheet of the OSCE Border Management Staff College</a></strong><br /><br /><strong><span style="font-size: 11px; color: #aaaaaa;">14 June 2013</span></strong>
```

Nothing changed;

```
<td valign="top" width="620"><strong><a class="pub" href="images/pub/pub1.pdf" target="_self">Factsheet of the OSCE Border Management Staff College</a></strong><br /><br /><strong><span style="font-size: 11px; color: #aaaaaa;">14 June 2013</span></strong>

a.pub
{
font-size: 14px;
}
```

No changes;

```
<td class="pub" valign="top" width="620"><strong><a  href="images/pub/pub1.pdf" target="_self">Factsheet of the OSCE Border Management Staff College</a></strong><br /><br /><strong><span style="font-size: 11px; color: #aaaaaa;">14 June 2013</span></strong>

td.pub
{
font-size: 14px;
}
```

No effects;
It is using font of a tag from style.css file
I want to change font-size for only this a tag.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Strange it doesn't change, as `inline styles` are most specific, if style sheet has `!important` declared, it wont over ride, try this and see

```
<span style="font-size: 11px !important; color: #aaaaaa;">Hello</span>
```

Comment: Perfect, !important is being used in stylesheet. Thanks.

Comment: And this is the perfect reason why you shouldn't use `!important` in stylesheets. By the way, @FirdavsKurbonov I don't want to criticise or anything, but which HTML version are you using? Your example gives out mixed signals (HTML 3.2, HTML 4 or 5, XHTML...)

Answer (score 1):

use this attribute in style

```
font-size: 11px !important;//your font size
```

by **!important** it override your css

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem? Also note, some visitors use a _minimum font size_. This rule will have no effect then.

Answer (score 1):

You should analyze your style.css file, possibly using Developer Tools in your favorite browser, to see which rule sets font size on the element in a manner that overrides the one in a `style` attribute. Apparently, it has to be one using the `!important` specifier, which generally indicates poor logic and structure in styling.

Primarily, modify the style.css file so that it does not use `!important`. Failing this, add `!important` to the rule in `style` attribute. But you should aim at *reducing* the use of `!important`, not increasing it.