# PHP table styling

Tags: php, html, html-table

Can anyone help me figure out why some of the table styles work in this php and others do not?

I'm new to PHP and somewhat new to HTML in a class where I have a hard time understanding the instructor.

It is supposed to look like this
[image]

But when I change things I'm getting different results than I would in straight HTML. For example, the text size tag I have there now does nothing I tried bold as well. I tried CSS and couldn't get the spacing correct. the spacing is better now with the inline but I still can't get the text changed. What am I missing?  I have to use PHP and Echo rather than print or printf (which I think would negate needing a table at all)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>hw1</title>
    <h1>Multiplication Tables</h1>
    <style> 
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
echo '<table cellspacing="6" cellpadding="6">';
echo '<tr>';
  for ($i=1; $i<10; $i++) {
    for ($j=2; $j<10; $j++) { 
        $y = $i * $j;
        $x = "$j * $i = $y";
        echo "<td font-size = large>$x</td>";
    }
    echo '<tr></tr>';
      # code...
  }
  ?>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Side-note: shouldn't the `echo '<tr></tr>';` just be `echo '</tr>';` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is caused by:

```php
echo "<td font-size = large>$x</td>";
```

---

- The `font-size` should be inside a `style=""`:
- Css uses `:` instead off `=`

```php
echo "<td style='font-size: large'>$x</td>";
```

- [How to change font-size of a tag using inline css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121453/how-to-change-font-size-of-a-tag-using-inline-css)

Answer (score 0):

If dynamically creating it with logic in php makes it hard for you to get it right. A good practice would be to first create a static multiplication table in HTML. Try to make that one exactly like your assignment. When you know how the table should be structured and styled to get the exact same result then you can start by making your code dynamic with php.

```css
td { 
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Multiplication table</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>2 x 1 = 2</td>
    <td>3 x 1 = 3</td>
    <td>4 x 1 = 4</td>
    <td>5 x 1 = 5</td>
    <td>6 x 1 = 6</td>
    <td>7 x 1 = 7</td>
    <td>8 x 1 = 8</td>
    <td>9 x 1 = 9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2 x 2 = 4</td>
    <td>3 x 2 = 6</td>
    <td>4 x 2 = 8</td>
    <td>5 x 2 = 10</td>
    <td>6 x 2 = 12</td>
    <td>7 x 2 = 14</td>
    <td>8 x 2 = 16</td>
    <td>9 x 2 = 18</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>2 x 3 = 6</td>
    <td>3 x 3 = 9</td>
    <td>4 x 3 = 12</td>
    <td>5 x 3 = 15</td>
    <td>6 x 3 = 18</td>
    <td>7 x 3 = 21</td>
    <td>8 x 3 = 24</td>
    <td>9 x 3 = 27</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```